# Trying to Find Most Occurring Name in a File

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I have 4 text files that I want to read and find the top 5 most occurring names of. The text files have names in the following format "Rasmus,M,11". Below is my code which right now is able to call all of the text files and then read them. Right now, this code prints out all of the names in the files.

```
def top_male_names ():
    for x in range (2008, 2012):
        txt = "yob" + str(x) + ".txt"
        file_handle = open(txt, "r", encoding="utf-8") 

        file_handle.seek(0)

        line = file_handle.readline().strip()

        while line != "":
            print (line)
            line = file_handle.readline().strip()

top_male_names()
```

My question is, how can I keep track of all of these names, and find the top 5 that occur the most? The only way I could think of was creating a variable for each name, but that wouldn't work because there are 100s of entries in each text file, probably with 100s of different of names.

Comment: Look into `collections.Counter` in the standard library.

Comment: There is no need to `file_handle.seek(0)`. Delete that line with no fear.

Comment: +1 for Counter, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects which has an example almost identical to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the gist of it:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()

for line in file_handle:
    name, gender, age = line.split(',')
    counter[name] += 1

print counter.most_common()
```

You can adapt it to your program.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count a number of words in a text,  use regex.

For example

```
import re

my_string = "Wow! Is this true? Really!?!? This is crazy!"

words = re.findall(r'\w+', my_string) #This finds words in the document
```

Output::

```
>>> words
['Wow', 'Is', 'this', 'true', 'Really', 'This', 'is', 'crazy']
```

"Is" and "is" are two different words. So we can just capitalize all the words, and then count them.

```
from collections import Counter

cap_words = [word.upper() for word in words] #capitalizes all the words

word_counts = Counter(cap_words) #counts the number each time a word appears
```

Output:

```
>>> word_counts
Counter({'THIS': 2, 'IS': 2, 'CRAZY': 1, 'WOW': 1, 'TRUE': 1, 'REALLY': 1})
```

Now reading a file :

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('file.txt') as f: text = f.read()

words = re.findall(r'\w+', text )

cap_words = [word.upper() for word in words]

word_counts = Counter(cap_words)
```

Then you only have to sort the dict  containing all the words, for the values not for keys and see the top 5 words.